# how to test controller in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am writing directive and want to add unit tests. 
I want to write tests:

- it('When directive is created messages variable is defined')
- it('When directive is created it contains no messages')
- it('When message is called it will add new message to stack')

My directive code is as follows

```
app.directive("message", function () {
return {
    transclude: false,
    require: '^ngModel',
    templateUrl: 'notificationBar.html',
    scope: {
        message: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {  

        $scope.messages = [];

        $scope.addMessage=function(message){
            $scope.messages.push(message);
        }                           
    }
}
```

});

And my tests, but I am not sure why this does not work

```
describe("messageSpec", function(){
var element;
var $scope;
var ctrl;

beforeEach(module(app));
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $controller, $rootScope){
    var elm = angular.element(' <div data-message data-message="{{ message }}" >');
    $scope = $rootScope;
    element = $compile(elm)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();

    ctrl = element.controller("message");
}));

describe("test", function(){
   it('When directive is created messages variable is defined', function(){
       spyOn(ctrl,messages);

       expect(ctrl.messages).toBeDefined(); 
   });
   it('When directive is created it contains no messages',function(){
     spyOn(ctrl,messages);

     expect(ctrl.messages.length).toBe(0);
   });
   it('When message is called it will add new message to stack', function(){
     // todo
   });

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

These are a couple of things to consider.

1. There is a syntax error in the controller function at `$scope.addMessage(message){..`, so I just guess and fix it.
2. In the controller, `messages` is put into `$scope` not the controller instance itself (`this`) but in testcases you look for `messages` in the controller instance.
3. The `message` directive has an isolated scope, so a `$scope` that is passed into `$compile` cannot be tested against either.
4. As a workaround, you can use angular.element(..).isolateScope() to get the isolated scope for testing.

The working testcases should be like this:

```
describe("messageSpec", function() {
  var element;
  var $scope;
  var isolateScope;

  beforeEach(module("myApp"));
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $controller, $rootScope) {
    var elm = angular.element('<div data-message="{{ message }}">');
    $scope = $rootScope;
    element = $compile(elm)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();

    isolateScope = element.isolateScope();
  }));

  describe("test", function() {
    it('When directive is created messages variable is defined', function() {
      expect(isolateScope.messages).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('When directive is created it contains no messages', function() {
      expect(isolateScope.messages.length).toBe(0);
    });

    it('When message is called it will add new message to stack', function() {
      // todo
    });
  });
});
```

For the full example see: http://plnkr.co/edit/c2yeH3AMSt1Cp7MdF889?p=preview

Comment: in the preview i get error: "module is not defined" any idea why?

Comment: Did you see the error in my plunker? It works fine for me. If yes, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome and getting error: ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at Suite.<anonymous> (http://run.plnkr.co/WdBVohRCnTCT8los/appSpec.js:6:14)

Comment: The `module` variable is come from angular-mocks.js. Please check in the network tab in devtools to ensure that the file is loaded successfully.